# open graph action link not responding

Tags: facebook, facebook-opengraph

I have used open graph action to publish a story in facebook. I am able to publish and see the story. 
Problem is when I click the action link in the story.
I am getting no response when I click the action link in the open graph story posted. I am using sandbox mode for testing the flow and the server to server communication is not happening.

Comment: Hi, can you please post what you've already tried?

Comment: You need to supply some sample code before we can try and help you.

Comment: I am trying to redirect to our website when clicking the action link in the published story. I followed the documentation http://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/actionlinks/ and I have provided the end point url with json output {
          "redirect":"<redirect url>" 
      }